# Maven automatically downloading dependent jars

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I have recently started using maven to build my Java application. As Maven downloads the dependent jar(s), is there a chance that the functionality can break when my (unmodified) code is built with a newer version of the jar which maven automatically downloads? 
If it can, what is the workaround?

Comment: Maven doesn't automatically download a newer version - you have to specifically state which exact version it should be using. Are you perhaps talking about transitive dependencies that are pulled in automatically through other dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can and will happen.  Obviously you want to avoid 'code rot' where your code isn't updated to improved, newer, and supported APIs, however sometimes dependencies change their interfaces at inopportune times.

There are several [plugins](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) which provide more nuanced control over specific versions you depend upon.  I would recommend you minimize your dependency on pinned versions so you regularly benefit from bug fixes and updates to your dependencies.

Comment: Think of this scenario - some code is stored in a source repository. Assume that there is a piece of code which doesn't depend upon platform, e.g. math routines, string manipulations etc. which I really don't need to maintain over time so there is no such 'code rot' applicable in this case. How can one take a checkout of that code and tries to build it and finds that either it is broken

Comment: This sounds more like a continuous integration/testing problem.  Jenkins would be the current tool of choice for such things.